# How to call plugin function in appController in cakephp v2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am new in cake php . can you please tell how to call plugin function in app/controller function . I load the plugin but not getting how to use its function . thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot "call" a plugin (and especially not any function of it) - its just a container (folder) for classes. So what exactly are you trying to do? Please post some code.

Comment: @mark I made plugin Map in that a MapDirectionController with fetchMap() function in it .. i want to use that function in my app/controller ProjectController user() function. please tell how i fetch data of plugin in ProjectController user() function.thanks for replying

Comment: Well, thats just wrong. You dont use Controllers in other Controllers. Make it a Lib, a Model or some other more generic and reusable class.

Comment: @marc so i had to move my controller function in model in plugin Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you include a plugin you can easily use its models for example as:

```
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('PluginName.ModelName');
$this->ModelName->foo();
```

For libs and other classes App::uses() them:

```
App::uses('MyCoolPluginLib', 'PluginName.Lib');
$Lib = new MyCoolPluginLib();
```

Comment: I used this -- 

$this->MapDirection = ClassRegistry::init('Map.MapDirection');
$this->mapDirection->fetchData();

it gives error 

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchData() on a non-object

Comment: Tip: Case sensitivity is important for most OS and most programming languages.